# Polynomial function theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

The following is from Spivak chapter 3 page 49:
**Prove that for any polynomial function $f$, and any number $a$, there is a polynomial function $g$, and a number $b$, such that $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)+b$ for all $x$.**

So, I tried to prove by induction. I know that it is true for polynomial with n=1, suppose it is true for n=k, then for n=k+1, I have

$f(x)=a_{k+1}x^{k+1}+...+a_{1}x^1+a_{0}$

So, **my question is**: I do not know what to do next. Please help me complete this proof. I thank you very much.

Comment: I have already consult Spivak answer book, but it writes : $h(x)=f(x) - a_{k+1}(x-a)$ has degree <= k. I disagree: $f(x)$ has already assumed to have degree $k+1$, then minus $a_{k+1}x$ cannot degree its degree to $k$.

Comment: I think this answer book had a mistake: try defining $h(x) = f(x)-a_{k+1}(x-a)^{k+1}$ instead.

Comment: In fact euclidean division is applied. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_division. The problem is the reduced to : Prove that any polynomial $f$ can be divided by $x-a$ with rest $r$ of degree $<1$.

Comment: Eucledian division is very crude and is not as elegant as induction method, but I thank you nevertheless.

Comment: To Mike Earnest: I think your answer is wrong, but thank you nevertheless.

Comment: Mike is actually right,this is as far as I see the best way to reduce the degree of polynomial

Comment: OMG! Mike I thank you very much. How stupid I am. hehehehe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the answer book has an issue in it and here is the full proof to reassure you of that.

We can prove this theorem by induction on degree of polynomial $f(x)$ and here is how we proceed.

As usual for first step of induction we consider degree of polynomial one.Such polynomial is $$f(x)=cx +d =c(x-a) + (d+ca)$$ and thus the base case is proven.

Next we assume that it is true for all degrees up to $k$

Now for $k+1$ we have: $$f(x) = a_{k+1}x^{k+1}+...+a_{0}$$
We can take into consideration a polynomial of reduced degree:
$$h(x)= f(x) - a_{k+1}(x-a)^{k+1}$$

Since h(x) has degree less then or equal to $k$ by our induction hypothesis we have:
$$h(x) = (x-a)g(x) + b$$ otherwise expressed as $$f(x) - a_{k+1}(x-a)^{k+1} =(x-a)g(x) + b $$

After some algebraic manipulations we obtain that: $$f(x)=(x-a)[g(x) + a_{k+1}(x-a)^k] + b$$

And this proves the theorem

Comment: I thank you for your answer my friend !

Comment: If there are any difficulties feel free to ask,I am working through Spivaks book myself.

Comment: OH LALA. WE HAVE THE SAME COMMON GOAL !!! I am working through Spivak chapter 3. I have done every exercises in chapters before.Then I will try to read Rudin's notorious Principles of Mathematical Analysis. I hope we could discuss that as well my friend ^^!

Comment: One day soon enough... :D

Comment: I have a question for you Vanio, if you can look at it in time:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943358/problem-17-in-chapter-3-of-spivak-book . I thank you very much.

Comment: I cant tell you much except to understand that every positive number x can be written as square of some number,then you use multiplicative property given in hypothesis to conclude that it is greater then 0.For not being equal to zero,I do not get it either.Sleep on it and try in a few days,it helps to settle the mind

Comment: Thanks man !!! I appreciate it.

Comment: Why use $(x-a)^{k+1}$ rather than $(x-a)x^k$? Using the second makes the proof correspond directly to the Euclidean division algorithm.

Comment: I can not give a good answer to that,the choice of $(x-a)^{k+1}$ just worked so I did not bother with other possible choices,but I do agree that it would work